# opennebula-sunstone service faild

Tags: server, cloud, opennebula, novnc

I started out installing opennebula stable(v5.10) I have installed it on Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS.
after my installation has complete, but the service opennebula-sunstone doesn't start

Sunstone-server.conf:

```
# VNC Configuration
:vnc_proxy_base_port: 0
:novnc_path: /usr/share/opennebula/websockify/websocketproxy.py

# Default language setting
:lang: en_US

Occi-server.config:

:vnc_enable: yes

:vnc_proxy_port: 0
:vnc_proxy_path: /usr/share/opennebula/websockify/websocketproxy.py
:vnc_proxy_support_wss: yes
:vnc_proxy_cert:
:vnc_proxy_key:

# dpkg -l | grep novnc
novnc 1:0.4+dfsg+1+20131010+gitf68af8af3d-7     all    HTML5 VNC client - daemon and programs
python-novnc  1:0.4+dfsg+1+20131010+gitf68af8af3d-7   all    HTML5 VNC client - libraries

client - libraries
```

error

```
Failed to start OpenNebula noVNC Server.
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed problem With reinstall sunstone and ruby packages by gems

```
sudo /usr/share/one/install_gems sunstone rubydevelopmentlibrary

systemctl start opennebula-novnc.service

Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/opennebula-novnc.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2020-03-01 18:08:08 +0330; 1 day 17h ago
 Main PID: 959 (python)
    Tasks: 1
   Memory: 13.4M
      CPU: 15.896s
   CGroup: /system.slice/opennebula-novnc.service
           └─959 python /usr/share/one/websockify/run --target-config=/var/lib/one/sunstone_vnc_tokens 29876
```